# UNIX time is too long

Tags: python, unix, cookies, time

I've got this number **13008365973607952** and I know that it corresponds to **Thursday, 21 March 2013 19:59:33**. However, for me this number seems too long. When I use Python's `time.time()` function I get only **1363901872.498432**, which is as long as mention before if you drop the dot, but then it becomes too big (value).

Can anyone tell me how to get such a valid number?

Comment: Where did you get that time? to me, it looks like a modification time based on windows Active Directory standard which, doesn't follow the same starting point as unix (1970... etc).. So, what's the source of this time?

Comment: @Torxed Google Chrome's Cookies database (SQLite), it's labeled *creation_utc*

Comment: Ah yea i had some boner issues with that as well, tried to create a parser that would check my "last visit" to a page and then warn me if any passwords on that page was old enough that i should consider changing them or even cancel any account on that page since i didn't visit it in a while... anyway i think they use the same time-method as Active Directory for some reason, check out my solution and give it a go :) (note: Chrome stores in two different time-formats odd enough)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
secsAfterADEpoch = float(your_weird_time) / 10000000.0 # seconds since jan 1st 1601
ADToUnixConvertor = ((1970-1601) * 365.242190) * 86400 # unix epoch - AD epoch * number of tropical days * seconds in a day
unixified = (secsAfterADEpoch-ADToUnixConvertor)+31800 # unix Timestamp version of AD timestamp + correction time
```

Erm try this?

Note: `+31800` was something i had to add to the equation most likely to my timezone or some mathematical issue in the previous calculations.. so if your's doesn't work keep in mind i'm +1 GMT (or CET) so removing it or changing it accordingly might be a good idea if you get close results but not spot on :)

Comment: Exactly. Just to complement: [«The FILETIME structure represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601»](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188768)

Comment: Yw, and @9000 +1 for useful comment, i had to figure out this the hard way a month back (didn't have any internet when doing the coding).. so yea thank you :)

Comment: @Robin92 oh and don't forget to mark your question as answered if you think it's solved :)